# Why is there a problem with the configuration file for nginx

Tags: nginx, flask

[image]

Please help me figure it out, I've been trying to solve this problem all day today. I am installing flash on an ubuntu server. I do everything according to the manual https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04-ru

I get to step 5. Up to this point, everything works. The test server starts on port 5000. Everything is OK. But I can't figure it out any further.

Creating a file *myproject.service*

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=norootuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/norootuser/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/norootuser/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/norootuser/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --ini myproject.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I don't understand what to do here, I did everything according to the instructions, but I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your project file permission is not correct

try both of these

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/norootuser/myproject
chmod -R 700 /home/norootuser/myproject
```

if not works let's try with root permission should probberly works

```
chown -R root:root /home/norootuser/myproject
chmod -R 700 /home/norootuser/myproject
```

Also try `sudo` too